# Event triggered definition of array elements gives wrong values

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

The purpose of this model is to provide the indexed elements of the "vector" array the values of the array "tester", which are increasing numbers from 1 to 12.
This shall happen every time the BooleanPulse is true. The arrays are indexed by the Integer `counter`, which increases by 1 every boolean pulse.

The model simulates but gives every "vector" element the value 0. Also the warning message is "Failed to solve linear system of equations (no. 21) at time 0.000000. Residual norm is 0.5."

```
model Array_Test_simple
  Real vector[12];
  Integer counter;
  Real tester[12]=1:1:12;
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.BooleanPulse booleanPulse(period = 0.1);

initial algorithm
  counter:=1;
algorithm
  when booleanPulse.y then
    vector[counter]:=tester[counter];
    counter:=pre(counter)+1;
  end when;

equation

annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "4.0.0")));
end Array_Test_simple;
```

Comment: In Dymola 2022x this works until 1.3s which is when it complains, that the index is out of bounds (which makes sense, given the counter is not reset). So I expect it to be a tool-related issue...

Comment: Works means e.g. vector[8] is 0 until 0.8s and then changes to 8.

Comment: yeah thats how it should be. the 8th trigger is on 0.8s so thats when vector[8] is redefined. its a pity it works in dymola but not in openmodelica... its some kind of weird, if i replace the type real of the arrays with type integer , it works all fine

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/8492) in OpenModelica and was recently fixed in [PR #8541](https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/pull/8514).
Try out the latest [nightly-build](https://openmodelica.org/download/download-windows) of OpenModelica and check if that solves your issue.

[image]

But four your example it should also work to use equations and not algorithm equations. In general they are supported much better and the compiler can try to optimize them. Algorithms stay basically untouched.

Comment: thank you very much, i will test both ways. i kinda thought it would be a bug bc as i said above it totally works with the type integer.

Comment: FYI: the nightly build solved the problem, indeed, where the use of equation gave didn't work: the failure message was that there are too many variables and less equations. i think thats bc OpenModelica indentifies  vector[counter]=tester[counter] as one equation